# How to draw a huge number of dots (with regular pattern) on canvas?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, canvas, graphics

The dots are arranged so they have a regular distance between them.

they are drawn at (x%4==0) and (y%4==0), they take time to be drawn in a brute force way:

```
for (var x = 0; x < width; x+=4) {
    for (var y = 0; y < height; y+=4) {
        draw(x, y, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

how to do it in a better way?

[image: dotted image]

Comment: What does draw() do? You can use a pattern (i.e. `createPattern()`).

Comment: `draw(x,y,width,height);` just does `canvas.getContext("2d").fillRect(x,y,width,height);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`createPattern()`](https://devdocs.io/dom/canvasrenderingcontext2d/createpattern) by first creating an offscreen-canvas, draw a single dot into it, then use that canvas as a image source for `createPattern()`. Set pattern as `fillStyle` and fill.

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var pattern = ctx.createPattern(createPatternImage(), "repeat");
ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

function createPatternImage() {
  var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
  ctx.canvas.width = ctx.canvas.height = 4;   // = size of pattern base
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,1,1);
  return ctx.canvas;                          // canvas can be used as image source
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c style="background:#c00"></canvas>
```

If this is not an option you can always optimize the code you have now by not filling each dot, but adding to the path and fill once:

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");   // obtain only one time.
var width = c.width, height = c.height;

ctx.beginPath();                // clear path if it has been used previously
ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";          

for (var x = 0; x < width; x+=4) {
    for (var y = 0; y < height; y+=4) {
        draw(x, y, 1, 1);
    }
}

// modify method to add to path instead
function draw(x,y,width,height) {
  ctx.rect(x,y,width,height);
}

// when done, fill once
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id=c style="background:#c00"></canvas>
```